# App-Engine directing endpoint to previous class name, now 404 not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've been using App-Engine as the backend for an Android and iOS application.  It's been working without problem with both the local development server (over http) and actual app-engine (over https).

Then I noticed that, while renaming endpoints, I accidentally duplicated a word in the class name of an endpoint: `RegionRegionIconsEndpoint` instead of simply `RegionIconsEndpoint`.  It was a 1-line fix.

```
public class RegionRegionIconsEndpoint {
    @ApiMethod(name = "getRegionIcons", path="regionIcons", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public RegionInfoVersion.RegionIcons getRegionIcons(User user, @Named("id") String id)
            throws OAuthRequestException {
        ...
    }
}
```

became

```
public class RegionIconsEndpoint {
    @ApiMethod(name = "getRegionIcons", path="regionIcons", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public RegionInfoVersion.RegionIcons getRegionIcons(User user, @Named("id") String id)
            throws OAuthRequestException {
        ...
    }
}
```

I generated new cloud-endpoint libraries and continued development using the local development server.  All good.

When I deployed it to the real App-Engine service, however, a problem arose.  When my app starts, there are a series of calls to other endpoints defined just as the one shown above; these always work fine.  Then there are calls to this endpoint.  A typical call looks like this:

```
POST https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/client/v1/regionIcons?id=foo
```

Authorization is also provided and the expected result comes back most of the time... say 80%.  The AE logs look like this:

```
2014-05-02 21:36:30.551 /_ah/spi/com.example.app.endpoints.RegionIconsEndpoint.getRegionIcons 200 48ms 0kb Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip) module=default version=1
70.80.59.221 - - [02/May/2014:18:36:30 -0700] "POST /_ah/spi/com.example.app.endpoints.RegionIconsEndpoint.getRegionIcons HTTP/1.1" 200 149 - "Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip)" "my-app.appspot.com" ms=49 cpu_ms=41 cpm_usd=0.000017 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=006c1b117c1b2d35341e0f407ae5785a825b65e5
```

The remaining times, I get a `404 Not Found` response and the AE logs have this:

```
2014-05-02 21:36:30.852 /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages 204 16ms 0kb module=default version=1
10.1.0.41 - - [02/May/2014:18:36:30 -0700] "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages HTTP/1.1" 204 0 - - "my-app.appspot.com" ms=16 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=006c1b117c1b2d35341e0f407ae5785a825b65e5
E 2014-05-02 21:36:30.851
Request URL: https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/client/v1/regionIcons?id=foo
Method: client.getRegionIcons
Error Code: 404
Reason: notFound
Message: service 'com.example.app.endpoints.RegionRegionIconsEndpoint' not found

2014-05-02 21:36:30.802 /_ah/spi/com.example.app.endpoints.RegionRegionIconsEndpoint.getRegionIcons 404 16ms 0kb Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip) module=default version=1
70.80.59.221 - - [02/May/2014:18:36:30 -0700] "POST /_ah/spi/com.example.app.endpoints.RegionRegionIconsEndpoint.getRegionIcons HTTP/1.1" 404 166 - "Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip)" "my-app.appspot.com" ms=16 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000019 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=006c1b117c1b2d35341e0f407ae5785a825b65e5
```

You can see on the `Message` line that, sometimes, AE is still trying to process the call using the old class name with the duplicated word!  I've done searches over my entire code-base and the generated files and I cannot find the string "RegionRegion" anywhere.  I've checked the `web.xml` file a dozen times and it has only the new "RegionIconsEndpoint" class name.

Wondering if somehow Google's servers were keeping old information around, I deployed the new version of my app as `2-dot-my-app.appspot.com`.  The behavior remains exactly the same *except* that there are no AE log messages for the requests that fail with 404 on this version.  Successful request logs are as before.

Both my Android and iPad apps are experiencing this.  In addition, I've managed to reproduce it using the web and Google's API explorer on my-app.appspot.com.  In this last case, a successful request shows this:

```
200 OK

cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  171
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sat, 03 May 2014 03:07:05 GMT
etag:  "G170GGjYGsLnxTffzUEJmTttHzU/LUWzmydK3mjH7IeRbEc_n9J6cDQ"
expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:  no-cache
server:  GSE

{
 "iconsVid": "foo",
 "iconsVersion": 3,
 "kind": "client#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"G170GGjYGsLnxTffzUEJmTttHzU/LUWzmydK3mjH7IeRbEc_n9J6cDQ\""
}
```

and a failed request shows this:

```
404 Not Found

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  169
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sat, 03 May 2014 03:08:34 GMT
expires:  Sat, 03 May 2014 03:08:34 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "service 'com.example.app.endpoints.RegionRegionIconsEndpoint' not found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "service 'com.example.app.endpoints.RegionRegionIconsEndpoint' not found"
 }
}
```

again clearly showing an access to the old class name.  When trying to do the same to the v2 version that I deployed (2-dot-my-app.appspot.com), it's different.  A success request ends like this:

```
200 OK

cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  171
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sat, 03 May 2014 03:12:08 GMT
etag:  "EP5CWx59se1v4KdDnkfEx7cTkis/LUWzmydK3mjH7IeRbEc_n9J6cDQ"
expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:  no-cache
server:  GSE

{
 "iconsVid": "foo",
 "iconsVersion": 3,
 "kind": "client#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"EP5CWx59se1v4KdDnkfEx7cTkis/LUWzmydK3mjH7IeRbEc_n9J6cDQ\""
}
```

and a failed request ends like this:

```
404 Not Found

cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  29
content-type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sat, 03 May 2014 03:06:10 GMT
expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:  no-cache
server:  GSE

Not Found
```

I don't know what else to try.  To me, it looks like a bug in App-Engine.

*So... any ideas what is going on here and how to fix or work around it?*

**2014-05-04:** I tried changing the method from `POST` to `GET`: exact same behavior.  I tried changing the path from `regionIcons` to `regionIconsFoo`: exact same behavior.  I tried changing the @API version from `v1` to `v2`: exact same behavior.

Finally, I tried changing the name of the class back to the previous (with the duplicated word):  I get fewer failures (maybe 5% instead of 20%) but they still occur with the failing requests trying to access the now non-existent class name *without* the duplicated word.

Restoring the correct name resumes the originally described behavior with the original failure rate.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with similar problem. Check logs on appengine.com project site. You should see log about updating, if it has additional info about error - check it. 
Sometimes AE works on local machine well but deployment process reveals some bugs.

**Edit:**

**1**. Rename the class back to old "double" name, upload it to AE and check if all requests are working without a bug, if yes, rename the class again. (if it's appengine bug it should fix it).

**2**. Create as simple as possible api and substitute it with your project. Update it to AE and check with api explorer is everything ok, without methods from your main project. If it's ok, once again swap "test" project with your true one and upload to AE.

Comment: That's http://appengine.google.com/ and the Admin Logs show "Successfully updated API configuration" for both the original version=1 deployment and the new version=2 deployment.

Comment: Brian, open <api-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer and check if all api's names and methods are good.

Comment: Yes, they all look and behave as expected except this one which fails 20% of the time referencing and old class name.  Granted, it was the only endpoint that had a change in the class name.

Comment: I saw your edit just as I was coming here to add an update to the report.  For my next trick, I'm going to include _both_ old and new class names to see what occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer because it doesn't address the cause, but it is my *solution*.

I duplicated the working class back into the old class name.

```
public class RegionRegionIconsEndpoint {
    @ApiMethod(name = "getRegionIconsOld", path="regionIconsOld", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public RegionInfoVersion.RegionIcons getRegionIcons(User user, @Named("id") String id)
            throws OAuthRequestException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now in the log, even though I'm only ever calling `getRegionIcons`, I see indications that both classes are being called with the "old" version handling about 20% of the requests.  It's a hack and I don't like it, but it works and the clients are happy with it.

*If you can't beat 'em, join 'em.*

Comment: Several weeks later, I uploaded a new version that did **not** have the old class.  No problems.  It seems that AppEngine must have remembered the previous endpoint->classname association and picked semi-randomly between old and new.  After enough time, the previous association had been completely forgotten and the problem went away.